# How to select certain data in a column and compare that to other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

What i'm trying to achieve is to compare specific data in one field to another field. Back story here is, that i run an arma server that uses SQL tables with data and controls game items and player data. My ultimate end goal is to have a statement that will remove objects where a player hasn't been logged in for x amount of days.

The data i'm focusing on is in my object.data table and worldspace column. data looks like this for example:

'[179.361,[3944.11,7453.54,0.355],"12345678912345678"]'

What i need to be able to do is select the "12345678912345678" number and compare that to two columns and output results that equal.

I would switch the CharacterID to worldspace if could get the select to find only that ending number

```
SELECT o.`Classname`
     , p.`PlayerName`
     , o.`CharacterID`
     , c.`LastLogin`
FROM `Object_DATA` o
    , `Player_DATA` p
    , `Character_DATA` c
WHERE p.`PlayerUID`=o.`CharacterID`
    AND c.`PlayerUID`=p.`PlayerUID`
    AND c.`Alive`=1
    AND o.`CharacterID` IN (SELECT `PlayerUID`
                            FROM `Character_DATA`
                            WHERE `Alive`='1'
                                AND DATE(`LastLogin`) < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

The below select works but the data isn't matching the table:

```
SELECT o.`classname`
     , p.`PlayerName`
     , o.`Worldspace`
     , c.`LastLogin` 
FROM `Object_DATA` o
    , `Player_DATA` p
    , `Character_DATA` c 
WHERE o.`Worldspace` LIKE '[%,[%,%,%],"123%"]'
  AND c.`PlayerUID`=p.`PlayerUID`
  AND c.`Alive`=1 IN (SELECT `PlayerUID`
                      FROM `Character_DATA` 
                      WHERE `Alive`='1'
                          AND DATE(`LastLogin`) < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 month)
```

In the end all I want to know, is if there is a way to select data in a field and compare just that set of info to another column with similar data. EX: playerUID will match the "12345678912345678" in the worldspace.

Hope that was clear enough and i couldn't find anything that explained this for me else where. I apologize if i missed it.

Comment: I suggest re-formatting the code in your question to make it readable, you can highlight a code section and hit the `{}` button to set it apart as code, and some carriage returns and indents would go a long way. Also you've got both `mysql` and `sql-server` tagged.  Additionally, you should ditch the deprecated join syntax.

Comment: Why is this tagged `MySql` and `sql-server`? From the syntax I would guess it's MySql...

Comment: My apologies. Tags are adjusted and this was my first post and didn't see the formatting tools initially.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for, but if your just wanting to find `Worldspace` values that end in that id, then do this:

```
WHERE o.`Worldspace` LIKE '%_12345678912345678__'
```

OR

```
WHERE o.`Worldspace` LIKE '%"123%"]'
```

My guess is that you don't really need to specify what values are before the id if you know that the id is always going to be at the end of the value.

Comment: Thank you zachary4613, that is on the right track for sure. I wasn't sure if i could use the % to exclude the beginning value and only focus on the ID/ending value which will always post in that section when a player updates an item. The value i want to retrieve or compare is the ending value in quotes. I will test this when i get home tonight and report back.